Issues with Serving Django App via Subpath in Apache
I have a Django application (Django version 4.2.11) that I want to serve under a subpath using Apache. Specifically, I want to serve the app at https://example.com/subpath so that other Django app URLs can be accessed as subpaths. For example:

https://example.com/subpath/admin should load the Django admin page.
https://example.com/subpath/api should load the API endpoints.

However, I am encountering a 404 error when I try to access these URLs.
Here is my current Apache configuration to redirect Django app to a subpath:
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    SSLEngine on
    RewriteEngine on

    # Redirect /subpath to INTERNAL_IP:8000
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/subpath
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} =websocket
    RewriteRule /(.*) ws://INTERNAL_IP:8000/$1 [P,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/subpath
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} !=websocket
    RewriteRule /(.*) http://INTERNAL_IP:8000/$1 [P,L]

    ProxyPass /subpath http://INTERNAL_IP:8000/
    ProxyPassReverse /subpath http://INTERNAL_IP:8000/
    ProxyRequests Off

</VirtualHost>

My Django urls.py file:
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
from my_app.management.commands import run_schedules

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include('my_app.urls')),
    path('api/', include('auth_app.urls')),
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)

admin.site.site_header = 'My API Administration'
admin.site.index_title = 'My API Admin Area'
admin.site.site_title = 'My API Administration'

scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
scheduler.add_job(run_schedules.Command().handle, 'interval', minutes=0.50)
scheduler.start()

Issue
Despite these configurations, I'm still encountering a 404 error when trying to access https://example.com/subpath/admin. The URL http://INTERNAL_IP:8000/admin works fine.
Steps I've taken so far but still not resolving the issue

Updated the Apache configuration to handle the subpath and restarted Apache.
Updated Django urls.py to include the /subpath prefix.
Set FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME in settings.py.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.
